# Strange C# Behavior

Tags: c#, exception

I have this function in C# which loads elements in a PropertyGrid.

```
public void LoadElements(Document selectedDocument)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.PropertyGrid != null)
        {
            DocumentProperties DP = new DocumentProperties(selectedDocument);
            if(DP != null)
            {
                this.PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = DP;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { Logger.LogError(ex); }
}
```

The problem is that it throws an exception everytime.

```
HRESULT -2147467261
The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.    
   in System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.set_SelectedObjects(Object[] value)
   in System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.set_SelectedObject(Object value)
   in FloatingForms.FloatingPropertiesForm.LoadElements(Document selectedDocument) dans         d:\DEV\FloatingForms\FloatingPropertiesForm.cs:ligne 108
```

I don't understand because I test if PropertyGrid is not null and if my DocumentProperties Object is not null. Evrything is not null but that doesn't work.

Could you help me to find a solution please ?

**EDIT**

I have a WPF grid in which there are Canvas. Everytime a Canvas is selected `Activated event` the following `Element_GotFocus` eventHandler is called.

```
private void Element_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (MyApplication.PropertiesPanel != null)
        {
            if (sender is Canvas)
            {
                if ((sender as Canvas).Tag != null)
                {
                    if ((sender as Canvas).Tag is Document)
                    {
                        if (MyApplication.PropertiesPanel != null)
                        {
                            MyApplication.PropertiesPanel.LoadElements((sender as Canvas).Tag as Document);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { Logger.LogError(ex); }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

**DocumentProperties Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Entities
{
    public class DocumentProperties
    {
        #region Properties

        private int m_iDocumentId;
        private string m_sDocumentName;
        private string m_sDocumentDescription;

        #endregion

        #region Getters / Setters

        public int Id
        {
           get { return this.m_iDocumentId; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
           get { return this.m_sDocumentName; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
           get { return this.m_sDocumentDescription; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public DocumentProperties(Document Document)
        {
            try
            {
                this.m_iDocumentId = Document.Id;
                this.m_sDocumentName = Document.Name;
                this.m_sDocumentDescription = Document.Description;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Logger.LogError(ex); }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

PS : Document Class is a complex object in which there is lots of designing properties I don't want to display in the propertygrid. That's why I defined DocumentProperties, to limit user access to properties.

Comment: What about `selectedDocument`?

Comment: Yeah, why don't put a guard around selectedDocument? Could be null?

Comment: It is OK. It implements a non null DocumentProperties object

Comment: Have you added anything into the ProperttGrid before attempting to select it?

Comment: I just tried adding a if(selectedDocument != null) but it's ok, it is not null

Comment: @gbjbaanb No, there is nothing in it. that's my only function which defines the selectedObject.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman - I'm not convinced that is a valid duplicate for this question, the op already has safeguards in place for NRE's but is still unable to solve their issue, T00rk, can you create a short reproducible problem to help? i'd imagine some property on one of your objects isn't set correctly which `SelectedObject` needs

Comment: I agree on that. Reopened. I guess it concerns the properties of the object too, that's why I sticked longer with the duplicate.

Comment: From what I see the OP is using Microsoft.Office.Core there? (for documentproperties and word.Document? or am I mistaken there?)

Comment: No DocumentProperties is a custom class I defined.

Comment: Does your property grid have objects in it? I'd imagine the issue would be something like that.

Comment: One of your properties in `DocumentProperties` is throwing a NRE.

Comment: @T00rk: Yes I did. I explained in the comment above. If not closed as duplicate, I would close as 'not reproducable' or 'unclear', since it isn't reproducable with this code only.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I'm gonna investigate on it ... Thank you all for your time

Comment: TOOrk: Leppie could have a point there. As you said it is a custom class it would be good to see the code for that class (especially also the constructor and the properties themselves of that class)

Comment: Did you see which line was throwing error?

Comment: @Thomas Nope, there is no problem with the `DocumentProperties` object. It only has 3 properties which are all defined. I'm in debug mode step-by-step, I put a break point just before  `this.PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = DP;` and every properties are defined. None of them throw an exception

Comment: @mrsrizan Yes this is this line  `this.PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = DP;`

Comment: @T00rk: Can you post the full code that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's a huge application. I can post the event which calls this function if you want, but I can't post all my source code.

Comment: I understand, but I am dying to paste something in VS to check the issue, but I can't...

Comment: @T00rk A really useful information would be the definition of DocumentProperties and Document, mainly their properties and any code the getter of those properties might call.

Comment: Sorry but I really can't post all my Solution. There is 12 projects in it

Comment: @T00rk: Place a try/catch around every getter in `DocumentProperties`. Even better, attach a debugger and tell it to break on all handled exceptions. This will give you the exact location.

Comment: for your answer to my inquiry: how did you then define propertygrid? (never used it myself but possibly that the problem then lies with that one)

Comment: FYI, there is a tool called dotPeek. It can server as a symbol server for the VS debugger and if you set it up you can actually step into the .NET framework code.

Comment: @Thomas I simply defined it using visual designer. I haven't changed any properties.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your time, I'm gonna find another way to do that without using propertygrid ...